# How to update formik field values of parent component from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a Parent component, how can I update parent component field from child component using `setFieldValue` function of `formik`.

```
const [mulVal, setMultiValues] = useState([])


                <Field name='RollNo'>
                 {({ field, form }) => (
                  <FormControl isInvalid={form.errors.RollNo && 
                  form.touched.RollNo } isRequired>
                  <FormLabel htmlFor='RollNo '>Roll No</FormLabel>
                  <ChildComponent {...field} 
                  values={mulVal} options={data.RollNo }
                   onChange={setMultiValues}/>
                  <FormErrorMessage>{form.errors.RollNo } 
                  </FormErrorMessage>
                </FormControl>
              )}
```

Comment: Show some code ? what have you done till now

Comment: @Sakshi I have update with the code